# How do I bind xml from a file to a WPF Treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure this out. From what I understand I need to use an XmlDataProvider but while debugging I see that it doesn't contain any data.

Can someone demonstrate how to do that?

Comment: Also : please don't post solutions where any of the xml is used as a resource - that's not what I'm after - plenty of that over the network.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [this blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/tolong/archive/2006/12/20/bind-controls-to-rss-feed-using-wpf.aspx).

Here, they're binding to XML that's being pulled from an RSS feed.  It walks through the process in pretty good detail.